# Colouring old, unreplied to email in Outlook 2007

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I would like to use the "automatic formatting" of Outlook to create a rule similar to "expired emails" - but for the case when a sender hasn't set an expiry date on the email (which is most of the time).

I can see a rule about setting the time received is today, yesterday etc. - but I would like to set a condition "more than two days ago".

Is this possible? How can I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a conditional format (I believe this was called Automatic formatting before) with the condition `Expires` - `On or before` - `two days ago`, or `three days ago` if you wanted it exclusive of two days before.

[image]

You can also tick the `More Choices` -> `Only items that are:` -> `Unread` if that is what you wanted. Also, make sure you uncheck the current `Expired Emails` check box, or that will likely override your new formatting.

Comment: Thank you - that's got it. I hadn't seen anything before about the the natural language way of expressing dates in the filters.

Comment: @nwaltham Nothing to me feels more unnatural than giving a natural expression ;)

Comment: :-D - Yes - Agreed!!!